# if() statement behaviour, why does this pass into the loop?

Tags: c#, if-statement, parameters

i've came across a simple loop which seems to go into the loop regardless of a parameter i query in order to determine whether the loop should process. Below is the loop;

```
  if (result[4] == 0x01 || result[5] == 0x01 || result[6] == 0x01 || result[7] == 0x01 || result[8] == 0x01 || result[9] == 0x01 & deviceState == false)
                {

                        deviceState = true;
                        mainUI.setAlarmColour(result, device);

                }
```

note: i've tried "&" and "&&" for the final parameter, but both make no difference.

With this loop, even if deviceState is set to true, it proceeds to enter the loop. However, if i use the following loop it stops this issue:

```
  if (result[4] == 0x01 || result[5] == 0x01 || result[6] == 0x01 || result[7] == 0x01 || result[8] == 0x01 || result[9] == 0x01)
                {
                    if (deviceState == false)
                    {
                        deviceState = true;
                        mainUI.setAlarmColour(result, device);
                    }
                }
```

This second loops solves the problem and it no longer proceeds into the loop, meaning my function isn't called.

am I missing something fundamental here? I've tried messageBoxes to verify that it's false and they return the way I'd expect, yet it still enters the first loop.

Comment: && has higher precedence than ||

Comment: Where is loop? Its an if-else statement.

Comment: my bad, the loop is outside of the code snippets...guess that made my question title off, i'll change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First it's `&&` like you already tried (`&` is a bitwise operator), but you should group your `OR`s together and have the final `AND` standalone, like so:

```
if (
    (result[4] == 0x01 || result[5] == 0x01 || result[6] == 0x01 ||
     result[7] == 0x01 || result[8] == 0x01 || result[9] == 0x01)
   && deviceState == false)
{
    deviceState = true;
    mainUI.setAlarmColour(result, device);
}
```

Note that you can also change `deviceState == false` to simply `!deviceState` (if it's a non-nullable `bool`). `!` flips false to true for the comparison so you're essentially saying the exact same thing, albeit shorter.

*(Please ignore ugly formatting, just trying to show it clearer)*

Comment: +1 I would also break out the `result[i] == 0x01` chain into a method to give something like `if (!deviceState && ResultContainsValid(result))`, big if statements that say nothing should be refactored into methods that say something.

Comment: i get it now : ) guess it's one of those "you'll only know it if you know it" sorta things. Cheers!

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter The bracket `( ... )` is the important thing here since `A || B && C` means `A || (B && C)`, not `(A || B) && C` which you want. By the way, is `result` an array? I want to write all the checks for `0x01` in a shorter way.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, result is an array

Comment: I would also put `deviceState == false` at the beginning of the if statement as there is no point testing the array indices to only find out deviceState is true.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter Then you could say `if (!deviceState && Array.IndexOf(result, 0x01, 4, 6) != -1)) { ... }`. The number 6 is 10 minus 4, where 4 is the first index.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen this doesn't seem to work for some reason, or at least isn't returning the same values as my original, albiet long winded statement.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter Hmm, there's an extra `)` in my code that you should remove. But I believe `Array.IndexOf(result, 0x01, 4, 6) != -1` is `true` if one of `result[4]`, ..., `result[9]` is `0x01`, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i took out that extra ) but it still doesn't work for some reason. if i place my original statement in again it works. what is the -1 though?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter `-1` is the index returned if `0x01` is not found. If that byte **is** found, the index where it's found is returned (e.g. `7` if `result[7]` is first match). What is the contents of `result` and `deviceState` when it doesn't work?